# How to route Win7 VPN client traffic through alternate gateway

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, routing

I have two gateways, one chosen for speed and one chosen for volume, for cost considerations.

I use the Windows7 L2TP over IPSec VPN client to connect to work and I want to route this traffic though one gateway and the rest of my machine's traffic through the other gateway. I have set up static routes to send my work traffic through the VPN but the VPN then routes through the machines default gateway (.254) rather than the alternate (.253).

I can't find any way to configure the VPN client to use a different local gateway for it's cloud end.  I guess there must be a ROUTE command but I can't work it out.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I finally bumbled into my own answer:

I've been using 'NetRouteView' which is a free downloadable GUI utility to simplify access to the routing table and avoid using the ROUTE command in a cmd window.

1. Add the second gateway in the IP4 advanced properties of the network card.  Here they are on my local subnet

```
        192.168.1.254 (original landline router - unlimited use)
        and 
        192.168.1.253 (new, limited volume 4G router)
```

Each gate-way will add some lines to the routing table, for instance to handle low priority priority packets (I think) that look ike this:

```
  Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
    0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    192.168.1.253    192.168.1.104    266
    0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    192.168.1.254    192.168.1.104    210

                     (My local PC is on port     192.168.1.104)
```

2. Now we need to add a line to direct our (priority) VPN packets via the 253 gateway

```
   nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn  255.255.255.255    192.168.1.253    192.168.1.104     11

    nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn  IP address of your remote VPN server
    255.255.255.255  makes the route specific to this single address.
```

That works for me.  The only issue I now have is that after a reboot or waking from sleep the nnn line changes the gateway to the 254 address and I have to delete and re-enter it.  If I edit it,  NetRouteView complains 'Element not found'.  I have the line set as 'persistent or 'Don't Change' but the problem, rather than the line, persists.